# Toast not showing on screen

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have read the existing ionic 4 documentation but the following code does not show the toast. I am uploading .ts file code and .html file code. The condition inside the if() is checked, everything is working fine except the toast. If instead of a toast I try to code an alert, same happens; nothing is shown on the screen but no error messages are displayed...:

.ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { PostProvider } from '../../providers/post-provider';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/Storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  
  username: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private postPvdr: PostProvider,
    private storage: Storage,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async prosesLogin(){
    if(this.username != "" && this.password != ""){
      let body = {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password,
        aksi: 'login'
      };

      this.postPvdr.postData(body, 'proses-api.php').subscribe(async data =>{
        var alertpesan = data.msg;
        if(data.success){
          this.storage.set('session_storage', data.result);
          this.router.navigate(['/tabs']);
          const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
            message: 'Login Succesfully.',
            duration: 2000
          });
          toast.present();
          this.username = "";
          this.password = "";
          console.log(data);
        }else{
          const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
            message: alertpesan,
            duration: 2000
          });
          toast.present();
        }
   

   });

    }else{
      const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: 'Username or Password Invalid.',
        duration: 2000
      });
      toast.present();
    }
  }

  formRegister(){
    this.router.navigate(['/register']);
  }

}
```

.html code below:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-toolbar class="toolbar1">
            <ion-img class="logo" src="assets/img/logo_login.png"></ion-img>
        </ion-toolbar>
      <ion-item class="username">
        <ion-label position="floating">Username</ion-label><br>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username"></ion-input>
      </ion-item><br>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label><br>
        <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

    </ion-list>

    <div>
      <ion-button expand="block" padding color="tertiary" (click)="prosesLogin()">Sign In</ion-button>
     <!-- <ion-button expand="block" padding color="tertiary" fill="outline" (click)="formRegister()">Register</ion-button> -->
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: If you remove the condition will it work? Try to call directly and see if it works.

Comment: Not working either

Comment: The code is working fine for me [check here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-umnbjh?file=pages/home/home.ts) So maybe check that the condition works and that you have properly imported the `ToastController` from `'ionic-angular'`.

Comment: @luismiguelss I imported differently: `import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';`. Does it make any difference?

Comment: `'@ionic/angular'` is just a different package, there shouldn't be any problems with that.

Comment: Very strange, condition works fine, even if I take it off, toast still does not show... Any other ideas? Thank you for your time.

Comment: New update with the full code, in case it gives you any clue

Comment: Can you add this to stackblitz?

Comment: Do you try without route?